# How to test redirections in Bottle.py?

Tags: python, redirect, testing, pytest, bottle

I wanted to test redirection in my Bottle application. Unfortunately I did not find the way to test the redirection location. So far I was just able to test that the redirection was held, by testing that `BottleException` was raised.

```
def test_authorize_without_token(mocked_database_utils):
  with pytest.raises(BottleException) as resp:
    auth_utils.authorize()
```

Is there a way to obtain HTTP response status code or/and redirection location?

Thanks for help.

Comment: `Webtest` does what you want. https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/webtest/en/latest/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[WebTest](http://webtest.pythonpaste.org/en/latest/) is a full-featured and easy way to test WSGI applications. Here's an example that checks for a redirect:

```
from bottle import Bottle, redirect
from webtest import TestApp

# the real webapp
app = Bottle()


@app.route('/mypage')
def mypage():
    '''Redirect'''
    redirect('https://some/other/url')


def test_redirect():
    '''Test that GET /mypage redirects'''

    # wrap the real app in a TestApp object
    test_app = TestApp(app)

    # simulate a call (HTTP GET)
    resp = test_app.get('/mypage', status=[302])

    # validate the response
    assert resp.headers['Location'] == 'https://some/other/url'


# run the test
test_redirect()
```